# Why does the program always open http://--port=57883/ using IEDriverServer IE through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

Code trials:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
url = 'www.google.com'
def Login():
    browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe')
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get(url)
    print(browser.title)
    browser.find_element_by_id("register").click()
    time.sleep(9)
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(9)
    browser.quit()

Login()
```

when I run this python file in terminal, it always jumps to the page which names (http://--port=57583/)
and I don't know why

---

#### 20191125 ADD

```
browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get(url)
```

when I run this login.py
the new error is coming out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ou/PycharmProjects/accessw/login.py", line 32, in <module>
    ie()
  File "C:/Users/ou/PycharmProjects/accessw/login.py", line 14, in ie
    browser.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\ou\PycharmProjects\accessw\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\ou\PycharmProjects\accessw\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ou\PycharmProjects\accessw\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Specified URL (www.google.com) is not valid.
```

---

#### 20191126 ADD

Finally, it took me about three hours to figure out What's wrong with it !

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

I need to create a DWORD(32bit both) value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver on IE11 always has "--port=" in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831750/selenium-webdriver-on-ie11-always-has-port-in-url)

Comment: Ok, I got that but a new problem is coming out. (This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.)

Comment: You need to navigate to valid url, before that it shows above message by default. Please refer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/ie-always-opens-with-random-local-host-and-message-this-is-the-initial-start-p

Comment: Got that. I set a wrong registry entry(Regedit 64-bit Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### executable_path

[executable_path](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) is the parameter through which users can pass the **absolute path** of the *IEDriverServer* binary overriding the **system path** of *IEDriverServer* binary to be used to initiate an IE session.

So while invoking the *Key* **executable_path**, instead of passing the *absolute path* of the **`iexplore.exe`** you need to pass the *absolute path* of the **`IEDriverServer.exe`** as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

`get()` method must have the protocol in url. So you should change:

```
url = 'www.google.com'
```

to:

```
url = 'http://www.google.com'
```